# How to check if a file was included more than once

Tags: php

I want to avoid including the same file multiple times, and I’d like to write a test asserting the file was only included once. I’m stuck trying to write this assertion.

As `get_included_files` only returns the name of the file once, I can’t use this function to find if a file was included more than once.

I’d like not to use `debug_backtrace` as it doesn’t seem to work well with phpunit.

How can I do ?

Comment: If you use include_once instead of include, PHP will ensure the file isn't included multiple times, even if you accidentally write the command twice. Not sure this is really the subject of a functional unit test.

Comment: You’re talking about the implementation, the test purpose is to prove the file was included once only. I know I can use include_once but that’s not really what I’m asking (which is, how to assert the file wasn’t included more than once). Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: I'm confused -- if you use `include_once`, then you don't *need* to prove it was included once only, because you'd be relying on PHP's internal mechanism, which is already covered by a test. Otherwise, you have to rely on whatever side effect the inclusion causes, like incrementing a variable or making a log entry or whatever it does. You can't assert that the file was read twice unless you write your own include function.

Comment: `You’re talking about the implementation`...yes because it's an implementation feature. It's a compile-time action, not a runtime action. Including a file isn't something the application does, it's something the PHP interpreter does in order to successfully compile the program. You can't test that directly with a unit test. As Alex says above you can only test the indirect effects of it. You seem confused about what the purpose of a unit test is. Unit tests are supposed to test the application's functional specification, not whether PHP's internal functions do their job or not...

Comment: ...if the programmer decides to (help) implement a particular requirement by including a PHP script one or more times, that is not the concern of the tests or not. The test should test whether the specific application feature behaves as required. I very much doubt that including a script file is a feature in itself.